# Module parse failed: Unexpected character '@' when using React on Rails with Antd.

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs, webpack, antd, react-on-rails

I'm using React on Rails and have been trying to use Antd UI framework.

I have successully imported components from 'antd' like buttons and Datepickers

```
import { Button } from 'antd';
```

but they are not styled at all. Looking at my server I have the following error...

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/antd/lib/button/style/index.less
Module parse failed: Unexpected character '@' (1:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
| @import "../../style/themes/default";
| @import "../../style/mixins/index";
| @import "./mixin";
 @ ./node_modules/antd/lib/button/style/index.js 5:0-23
 @ ./app/javascript/packs/application.js

ERROR in ./node_modules/antd/lib/style/index.less
Module parse failed: Unexpected character '@' (1:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
| @import "./themes/default";
| @import "./core/index";
|
```

I have tried a few different ways to access the styles like directly references the specific stylesheet in my jsx file

```
//app/javascript/bundles/Page/components/Page.jsx
import React, { Component } from "react";

// import { Button, DatePicker } from 'antd'
import { Button } from 'antd';
// import Button from 'antd/lib/button';
// import 'antd/lib/button/style/css';

export default class Page extends Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <div >
        <Button type="primary">Primary</Button>
        <Button>Default</Button>
        <Button type="dashed">Dashed</Button>
        <Button type="danger">Danger</Button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

---

Looking at the Antd docs, I have followed the Importing on demand technique and added

```
"import", {
  "libraryName": "antd",
  "style": "css",  
  }
]
```

to my .babelrc file

https://ant.design/docs/react/getting-started#Import-on-Demand

I have also tried to install the `less` and `less-loader` as I'm pretty sure it has something to do with a css file containing an '@' which indicates to me that it is a less or sass file.

---

The only successful way I've been able to load the styles is by putting

```
@import 'antd/dist/antd.css';
```

in my app/assets/stylesheets/page.scss.

While this option works, it does not allow for the ability to `import on demand` and feels like the incorrect way to import the css as it uses the rails asset pipeline instead of webpack ( via webpacker)

Answer (score 0):

For me the issue was that I needed to have differently configured .less loaders in webpack for both the .less files found in antd's modules & the .less files I had written locally in my project.

For Antd I have this (Note that it's excluding /src/):

```
            {
            test: /\.(less)$/,
            exclude: [
                /\.(css)$/,
                /src/
            ],
            use: [
                MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
                {
                    loader: "css-loader"
                },
                {
                    loader: "less-loader",
                    options: {
                        javascriptEnabled: true,
                        modifyVars: get_theme()
                    }
                }
            ]
        },
```

And for my own .less files I have this:

```
            {
            test: /\.(less)$/,
            exclude: [
                /\.(css)$/,
                /node_modules/
            ],
            use: [{
                loader: 'style-loader' // creates style nodes from JS strings
            }, {
                loader: 'css-loader' // translates CSS into CommonJS
            }, {
                loader: "less-loader",
                options: {
                    javascriptEnabled: true
                }
            }]
        },
```

Versions of dependencies for this that I was using:

```
"css-loader": "^3.3.2",
"less": "3.10.3",
"less-loader": "^5.0.0",
"mini-css-extract-plugin": "^0.8.0",
"style-loader": "^1.2.1",
"antd": "4.4.2",
"webpack": "^4.43.0",
```